# How to set array URL query param in Vue with Vue-Router

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I am trying to set array query params with Vue-router, but I can't find a solution.

Currently the result is

```
http://localhost:8080/#/locations?page=1&categories=1&categories=2&categories=3
```

But my results should look like this

```
http://localhost:8080/#/locations?page=1&categories[]=1,2,3
```

This is my html

```
<router-link :to="{ path: 'locations', query: { page: 1, categories: [1,2,3] }}">
    {{ $root.trans.translate("locations") }}
</router-link>
```

Can you please tell me what do I need to do so my URL will be printed out as I wanted. If you need any additional informations, please let me know and i will provide. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do it in your logic in order to work as you expected

```
this.$router.push({
  path: 'path',
  query: {
    page: 1,
    categories: [1,2,3]
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on the [source](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/blob/9e4aa546/src/util/query.js#L77) it looks like this behavior is hard-coded. You might want to [open an issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues).

```
if (Array.isArray(val)) {
  const result = []
  val.forEach(val2 => {
    if (val2 === undefined) {
      return
    }
    if (val2 === null) {
      result.push(encode(key))
    } else {
      result.push(encode(key) + '=' + encode(val2))
    }
  })
  return result.join('&')
}
```

Comment: hmmm, do you see any other option to pass an array of values trough get param?

Comment: Vue should decode the `&foo=1&foo=2` back into an array. Is that not what you are seeing? Or do you not like how that format looks?

Comment: i was not satisfied with the forma. I already got answer. Thank you any way

Answer (score 1):

I worked around this by just `JSON.stringify`ing the array and setting that directly as a string. Here's some relevant code:

```
// use when query params include values that are arrays
export function queryParamIncludes(key, value) {
    let rawValue = router.currentRoute.query[key];
    if (rawValue == null) {
        return false;
    }
    let arr = JSON.parse(rawValue);
    return Array.isArray(arr) && arr.includes(value);

}

// append a value to the array at the given key
export function appendQueryParam(key, newValue) {
    let rawValue = router.currentRoute.query[key];
    let arr = rawValue == null ? [] : JSON.parse(rawValue);
    arr.push(newValue);

    let newQuery = {
        ...router.currentRoute.query,
        [key]: JSON.stringify(arr)
    };

    router.push({
        query: newQuery
    });
}

// Remove any value of the array at the given key.
// If the resulting array is empty, delete the whole key-value pair.
export function spliceQueryParam(key, valueToRemove) {
    let rawValue = router.currentRoute.query[key];
    if (rawValue == null) {
        return;
    }
    let arr = JSON.parse(rawValue);
    if (!Array.isArray(arr) || !arr.includes(valueToRemove)) {
        return;
    }

    arr = arr.filter(v => v !== valueToRemove);

    let newQuery = {
        ...router.currentRoute.query
    };

    if (arr.length === 0) {
        delete newQuery[key];
    } else {
        newQuery[key] = JSON.stringify(arr);
    }
    router.push({
        query: newQuery
    });
}
```